# Trying to use Google Sheets to connect to the Enphase solar API. Can't get the code to work?

Tags: api, google-sheets, solar

Background:
I have barely any knowledge of coding but I want to be able to use my solar output data from the Enphase system to trigger a hot water service to run. How I'm trying to do this is by moving the solar data into Google Sheets and when the solar generation is high enough, a button is pressed.

I've copied and changed this code from another question but I can't get it working. I am getting this error: Exception: Request failed for https://api.enphaseenergy.com returned code 401. Truncated server response: {"reason":"401","message":["Not authorized to access requested resource.","User not found."]} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response). (line 10, file "Enphase To Sheets").

I have no idea where to go from here. Any ideas what I've done wrong? Thanks

Code:

```
function getReport() 
{
var url = 'https://api.enphaseenergy.com/api/v2/systemskey=<apikey>&user_id=<userid>'

var token = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,{method:'POST',muteHttpExceptions: true});
var token_data = JSON.parse(token.getContentText());
var access_token = token_data.access_token

var url2 = 'https://api.enphaseenergy.com/api/v2/systems/1692404/stats&key<apikey>&user_id=<userid>'
var report = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2,{method:'GET',headers:{Authorization: 'Bearer ' + '<apikey>'}});
Logger.log(report)

SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetByName('Solar').getRange('A1').setValue(report); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're supposed to request an API key from them and they'll issue you one that you can put in the parts of your url with the < > symbols.

That is, you'll need a real api "key" and a real userid that you get from enphase.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah I've got the API key and the user-id. I didn't include it for security reasons. Even when I do include the real codes it doesn't run

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working. All I've changed is a few stupid little mistakes with question marks instead of '&'. Hope this helps someone else if you need it.
Once I had my data in the google sheet, I use =transpose(split(A1)) and then another split function to get the correct formatting to be able to use with IFTTT.

```
function getReport() 
{
  var url = 'https://api.enphaseenergy.com/api/v2/systems?key=<apikey_goes_here>&user_id=<userid_goes_here>'

  var token = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,{method:'POST',muteHttpExceptions: true});
  var token_data = JSON.parse(token.getContentText());
  var access_token = token_data.access_token

  var url2 = 'https://api.enphaseenergy.com/api/v2/systems/1692404/summary?key=<apikey_goes_here>&user_id=<userid_goes_here>'
  var report = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2,{method:'GET',headers:{Authorization: 'Bearer ' + '<userid_goes_here>'}});
  Logger.log(report)



  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Solar');
  sheet.getRange('A1').setValue(report)

}
```